# An open interval and a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Prove that if $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ is continuous and nondecreasing, then
$f ((c,d)) = (f(c), f(d))$, $(c,d) \subset [a,b]$

Let $y \in (f(c), f(d))$. Then by Intermediate value theorem there exists $x \in (c,d)$ such that $y = f(x)$. Thus $y \in f ((c,d)) $

Let $y \in f ((c,d)) $. Then there exists $x \in (c,d)$ such that $y =f(x)$. Since $f$ is nondecreasing, we have $f(a) < f(x) < f(b)$. Thus $y \in (f(c), f(d))$. Correct?

Comment: Please consider any constant function.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant: For any subintervals $(c,d)\subset [a,b]$ it follows $f((c,d)) = (f(c), f(d))$, then the statement is in general wrong.

Consider the constant function $f(x) = 0$ for every $x\in[a,b]$. Then, for any $a\le c < d \le b$ you have $f((c,d)) = \{ 0 \} \ne \emptyset = (0,0) = (f(c), f(d))$.